# Octave / Gradient Descent code: GD works fine, but it won't save the output from the cost function

Tags: machine-learning, octave, gradient-descent

The Gradient Descent part of this code works fine, but can anyone tell me why it's not initialising (or populating) the vector 'J_history'?

Here's the principal code:

```
data = load('ex1data1.txt'); %2 columns of data - a single x variable and a single y
X = [ones(m, 1), data(:,1)]; %adds a column of 1s to allow for an intercept term
y = data(:, 2);
m = length(y);
theta = zeros(2, 1); %initialising the vector of coefficient estimates at [0; 0]
iterations = 1500; %how many times to iterate the cost function
alpha = 0.01; %adjustment speed
theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations); %call the GD function
```

The last line of the principal code calls on function gradientDescent:

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
m = length(y);
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1); %I don't understand why this doesn't initialise (or generate an error)!
for iter = 1:num_iters
theta = theta - ((alpha/m)*(X*theta-y)'*X)'; %adjusting the coefficient for each iteration
J_history(iter) = computeCost(X, y, theta); %storing the output of the cost function at each iteration - again, I can't figure out why this doesn't work
end
end
```

And the 'J_history' line in the code above calls on the function computeCost:

```
function J = computeCost(X, y, theta)
m = length(y);
J = 0;
predictions = X*theta;
sqrErrors = (predictions-y).^2;
J=1/(2*m)*sum(sqrErrors);
end
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: How do you mean "not initialising" or "not populating"? Given your code, this should at the very least initialise `J_history` to be a 1500-by-1 array of all zeros.

Comment: Thanks @Adriaan - "not initialising" meaning when I've run the code, I have appropriate entries in the workspace for X, y, theta, alpha etc, but J_history isn't in there, not even as an empty vector

Comment: How do you run the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your gradient function with only one output argument:

```
theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations); %call the GD function
```

Your gradient function was defined to output two arguments:

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
```

In order to get the second argument out, you need to actually call this function with both output arguments:

```
[ theta, J_history ] = gradientDescent( X, y, theta, alpha, iterations );
```

In a statement like `[A,B,...] = funcname`, the `[A,B,...]` isn't an array; it is special syntax which tells octave how many output arguments to collect. If you only specify one output argument, like you have, then all other output arguments will be discarded.

See: https://docs.octave.org/latest/Assignment-Ops.html for details.